# Removing "last_" or "max_" from value string in Grafana

Tags: regex, grafana

I'm using Grafana 8.5 with this query

`SELECT last(/Fault \d\d*/) FROM "highres"."adapter" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval)`
How do I remove the `last_` from the result string (Fault Code)?
[image]
[image]

Solved with
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE` command to replace `last_` with `""`.
I have tested this on https://sqliteonline.com/. Which works as intended.
You may need to change the column name (the first parameter in the `REPLACE` function)

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(last(/Fault \d\d*/), "last_", "") AS fault
FROM "highres"."adapter" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($interval)
```

Comment: almost. but I get `InfluxDB Error: undefined function replace()`. Using `SELECT last(/Fault \d\d*/)  as "" FROM "highres"."ParamountPlus" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) ` is getting me closer (I just need to remove the _)

Comment: Try doing `SELECT last(/^Fault \d\d*$/)  as "" FROM "highres"."ParamountPlus" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval)`. If this doesn't work, what exactly does the `last()` function do in this context? Finding it difficult to find documentation for grafana.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Value Mapping: Regex `.*last_(.*)` → `$1`
[image]